# PGFPlots possible keys

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

The general structure of a plot is:

```
\begin{figure}                                                                   
    \centering                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}[OPTIONS_A]                                                        
        \begin{axis}[OPTIONS_B]                                                                                                                                       
            \addplot[OPTIONS_C]; 
            \addplot3[OPTIONS_D];                                      
        \end{axis}                                                               
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
\end{figure}
```

The `OPTIONS_A` are tikz options that I have never really needed. But I have questions about `OPTIONS_B` and `OPTIONS_C`. Is `OPTIONS_C` a subset of `OPTIONS_B`? Are there options exclusive to any of these groups? Furthermore, are `OPTIONS_C` and `OPTIONS_D` the same?

It seems that there are options exclusive to `OPTIONS_B` e.g. `xlabel`, `xmode`, etc. But it also seems that I can put any key from `OPTION_C` in `OPTION_B`, and it will just apply to all the plots. Is this correct?

In an attempt to learn more about PGFPlots I am writing a code generator, and the manual is not explicit about these key groups. Is the best option to consider these as 2 separate groups of keys (even if there is a lot of repetition), or is `OPTIONS_C` definitely a subset of `OPTIONS_B`?

Comment: I think `\addplot` creates its own group, so `OPTIONS_C` only affects that specific `\addplot` while `OPTIONS_B` affects the whole `axis` environment.

Comment: I guess "the manual is not very explicit" is because "the user can just do trial error"... which doesn't apply to code generator. It would be tough (or just do stress test on the generator)

Answer (score 3):

`OPTIONS_C` *might* be a subset of `OPTIONS_B` as far as the allowed option *names* are concerned (I'm not sure about that, though). However, the resulting plots can be very different, as the following examples show:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,width=4.5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[red]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[red] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[red]
    \addplot[] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot+[red] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```