# Style rows/columns of a `tikz-cd` diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-cd

Apparently, the tikz keys `row n`/`column n` don't work in `tikz-cd` diagrams:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, tikz}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}[row 1/.style={nodes={font=\color{red}}}]
            A \rar \dar & B \dar \\
            C \rar & D
        \end{tikzcd}
    \]
    \[
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix[matrix of math nodes, row 1/.style={nodes={font=\color{red}}}]{
                A & B \\
                C & D \\
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

I would have expected the first line of the first equation show up in red, like in the second. As you can see, this is not the case.

How can I achieve what I want, without applying the style to every node and every arrow?

**Edit:** The style for the nodes I can control with a `tikzcdset` before the diagram. But how about the arrows?

**Edit 2:** If possible, I'd like to have all arrows within row 1 red. If that's not possible, I'd be fine with all arrows starting in or defined in row 1.

Comment: Can you explain what outcome you want for the arrows? Are you looking for a way to make all the arrows in row 1 red? Or only the arrows *within* row 1 (i.e., from a row 1 cell to another row 1 cell)?

Comment: @SandyG See my Edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Nodes:

To change the style of a row use `nodes={row 1/.style=red}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}[nodes={row 1/.style=red}]
            A \rar \dar & B \dar \\
            C \rar & D
        \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

The other TikZ matrix options work similarly:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzcd}[nodes={every odd column/.style=red}]
    A \rar \dar & B \dar \rar & X \dar \\
    C \rar & D \rar & Y
\end{tikzcd}
```

### Arrows: [Note—there was an error in the earlier code.]

The arrows are more difficult. The reason is that the `\arrow` command (or its shortcuts) does nothing to the diagram at the point it is called. Initially, there is an empty `<paths>` string, and every time an `\arrow` command is encountered,

```
\path[⟨options⟩] (⟨source node⟩) to (⟨target node⟩);
```

is appended to `<paths>`. So to change the arrow colors for arrows in a certain row (say, row `<r>`), we have to get into the path of the arrows. The code is somewhat complicated, requiring some inserted code with `\pgfextra`, and then comparing the y-coordinate of the current `<source node>` with that of the `<r>-1` entry (located at `(\tikzcdmatrixname-<r>-1)`).

This is all put into a `tikzcdset` with a style called `rowarrows` (with `colarrows` defines similarly):

```
\tikzcdset{rowarrows/.style args={#1/#2}{arrows={to path={\pgfextra{\pgfsetstrokecolor{black}}
        (\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget) let \p1=(\tikztostart), \p2=(\tikzcdmatrixname-#1-1), \p3=(\tikztotarget) 
        in \pgfextra{\ifthenelse{\equal{\y1}{\y2}\AND\equal{\y3}{\y2}}
        {\pgfsetstrokecolor{#2}}{}}(\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget)}}},
    colarrows/.style args={#1/#2}{arrows={to path={\pgfextra{\pgfsetstrokecolor{black}}
        (\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget) let \p1=(\tikztostart), \p2=(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-#1), \p3=(\tikztotarget) 
        in \pgfextra{\ifthenelse{\equal{\x1}{\x2}\AND\equal{\x3}{\x2}}
        {\pgfsetstrokecolor{#2}}{}}(\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget)}}}}
```

Then when you call `\begin{tikzcd}[rowarrows=1/red]`, the result is

[image]

Note the syntax `rowarrows=<row number>/<color>`.

Combining this with the node solution from above:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[rowarrows=1/red, nodes={row 1/.style=red}]
    A \rar \dar & B \dar \rar & X \dar \\
    C \rar & D \rar & Y
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

You can mix and match node colors and arrow colors:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[rowarrows=2/blue, nodes={row 2/.style=red}]
    A \rar \dar & B \dar \rar & X \dar \\
    C \rar & D \rar & Y
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Coloring arrows in a column is similar:

[image]

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}[colarrows=1/red, nodes={column 1/.style=red}]
    A \rar \dar & B \dar \rar & X \dar \\
    C \rar \dar & D \dar \rar & Y \dar \\
    E \rar \dar & F \dar \rar & Z \dar \\
    G \rar & H \rar & W
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{2cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[colarrows=3/red, nodes={column 2/.style=red}]
    A \rar \dar & B \dar \rar & X \dar \\
    C \rar \dar & D \dar \rar & Y \dar \\
    E \rar \dar & F \dar \rar & Z \dar \\
    G \rar & H \rar & W
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

One shortcoming (at the moment) is that it is only possible to color the arrows in one row or in one column. Not both.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % needed for "let" operation

\tikzcdset{rowarrows/.style args={#1/#2}{arrows={to path={\pgfextra{\pgfsetstrokecolor{black}}
        (\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget) let \p1=(\tikztostart), \p2=(\tikzcdmatrixname-#1-1), \p3=(\tikztotarget) 
        in \pgfextra{\ifthenelse{\equal{\y1}{\y2}\AND\equal{\y3}{\y2}}
        {\pgfsetstrokecolor{#2}}{}}(\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget)}}},
    colarrows/.style args={#1/#2}{arrows={to path={\pgfextra{\pgfsetstrokecolor{black}}
        (\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget) let \p1=(\tikztostart), \p2=(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-#1), \p3=(\tikztotarget) 
        in \pgfextra{\ifthenelse{\equal{\x1}{\x2}\AND\equal{\x3}{\x2}}
        {\pgfsetstrokecolor{#2}}{}}(\tikztostart)--(\tikztotarget)}}}}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[rowarrows=1/red, nodes={row 1/.style=red}]
    A \rar \dar & B \dar \rar & X \dar \\
    C \rar & D \rar & Y
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{2cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[rowarrows=2/red, nodes={row 1/.style=red}]
    A \rar \dar & B \dar \rar & X \dar \\
    C \rar & D \rar & Y
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}[colarrows=1/red, nodes={column 1/.style=red}]
    A \rar \dar & B \dar \rar & X \dar \\
    C \rar \dar & D \dar \rar & Y \dar \\
    E \rar \dar & F \dar \rar & Z \dar \\
    G \rar & H \rar & W
\end{tikzcd}\hspace{2cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[colarrows=3/red, nodes={column 2/.style=red}]
    A \rar \dar & B \dar \rar & X \dar \\
    C \rar \dar & D \dar \rar & Y \dar \\
    E \rar \dar & F \dar \rar & Z \dar \\
    G \rar & H \rar & W
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that's where the `row n` key belonged. How did you find out? Do you also have a solution for the arrows?

Comment: @Bubaya: The arrows were a lot harder, but I have a solution now.

Comment: Wow, I'm deeply impressed by your Ti*k*Z magic! May I suggest that you replace your `row1arrows` by a generic two-argument `row n arrow` style? Tried it and it worked, but I didn't want to edit your answer.

Comment: @Bubaya: Finally got around to implementing your suggestion. Note: there was an error in the earlier code—it would color the wrong row in subsequent diagrams. Only the first diagram would work. This was due to using `tikz@f@1-#1-1` to identify the row position, but the first 1 refers to the diagram number. It needs to be replaced with `\tikzcdmatrixname-#1-1`, which took me a long time to find. It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Anyway, fixed now. The whole solution has been updated.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
           arrows =  {>=Straight Barb, very thick, gray}
           }
```

For color of nodes you can change their color only locally:

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,
    arrows =  {>=Straight Barb, very thick, gray}
}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
    \color{red}A \rar \dar & \color{red}B \dar \\
        C \rar & D
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hello Zarko ! I'm gonna edit your answer cause of an obvious missed copy/paste :)
However, for a reason I ignore, i cannot repaste your image.

Comment: SandyG's answer shows that the nodes' color can be changed not only globally.

Comment: @Bubaya As you can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643106/163874) you can apply styles locally or globally. Both answers are solution to your problem.